# Keybinds in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

I was typing in `Visual Studio Code` and I slammed at a lot of keys and from that moment for some reason when I press `ctrl + alt + n` I get `}` and can't run my program with that keysbind anymore eveh tho it stil says over the run button that `ctrl + alt + n` is stil shortcut for it, can someone please help me reset that so i can run my program with `ctrl + alt + n`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked here to see your existing shortcuts? The search box at the top is quite friendly:

File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts

Have you looked here to see the list of all commands, with their shortcuts (if any)?

View > Command Palette

Comment: Yes and as I said, it says that the bind is "ctrl + alt + N" for the code run, but when I press that it just writes "}". It is like that windows keybind takes priority over my Visual Studio Code command.